# Add badge to app icon in iOS 8 with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, icons, badge

I'd like to set a badge on the icon of my app like in apple's mail app (number on top of the icon).
How can I do this in Swift (iOS8)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The "number on top of the icon" is called a Badge. Badges can be set on a number of things besides Application Icons including Navigation Bar toolbar icons.

There are many ways to change the Application Icon Badge. Most use cases involve setting this when the Application is in the background to alert the user that there is some change that they may be interested in. This would involve a push notification.

For more on that see: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1

However, you can also change it while your app is active. You will need permission from the user by registering the UserNotificationType. Once you get permission, you can change it to whatever number you wish.

```
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Sound | UIUserNotificationType.Alert |
        UIUserNotificationType.Badge, categories: nil
        ))

application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 5
```

[image]

Comment: That's objective-c isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I translated it for you. Apologies for before.

Comment: You should add an explanation of what this code does. Otherwise, you're not teaching anyone anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what's `application`? I get an error (`use of unresolved identifier 'application'`).

Comment: I put it in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the AppDelegate File. You can also do this : let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication(). May have to import UIKit.

Comment: I received push notification in all state i.e. when app is in forground, background, close(terminated)..!
but my problem is that how to increment badge count when app is in background state and close (terminate) state???? 
Please tell me in details how i do it....?
my app badge count is only increase when app is in forground state.....?

if possible please tell me in brief.......!for Swift 3

Comment: Feel free to edit. I am not working in Swift iOS nowadays

Answer (score 35):

## 2019

The answer is simply

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 777
```

Unfortunately though it **will not work** unless you ask for permission first.

To do that you simply:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: .badge)
     { (granted, error) in
          if error == nil {
              // success!
          }
     }
```

Comment: and import UserNotifications where you request authorization

Answer (score 23):

ericgu's answer seems to be outdated. looks like this -> | got replaced.

Here is a working **Swift 2** code:

```
    let badgeCount: Int = 0
    let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge, .Alert, .Sound], categories: nil))        
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeCount
```

Edit: **Swift 3:**

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let badgeCount: Int = 10
        let application = UIApplication.shared
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeCount
    }  
}
```

[image]

Comment: Am i need to call this in a viewcontroller's view didload...? or can i call it in app delegate...?

Comment: @AbiramiBala you can literally call it wherever you want

Comment: I received push notification in all state i.e. when app is in forground, background, close(terminated)..!
but my problem is that how to increment badge count when app is in background state and close (terminate) state???? 
Please tell me in details how i do it....?
my app badge count is only increase when app is in forground state.....?

if possible please tell me in brief.......!for Swift 3

Answer (score 11):

For **iOS10**, **Swift 3** with **backward-compatibility**, you can wrap the best answers into a nice (static) utility function:

```
class func setBadgeIndicator(badgeCount: Int) {
    let application = UIApplication.shared
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
      center.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert, .sound]) { _, _ in }
    } else {
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil))
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeCount
  }
```

Comment: can we set Badge without registerForRemoteNotifications??

Comment: @PatelJigar, i don't think so. This badge function is designed to be updated via notifications

Comment: i had tried without registerForRemoteNotifications and it works

Comment: @Patal did you happen to try it on the same install that you had previously accepted permission for notifications. Try it on a fresh install...

Comment: @quemeful, may I know where this function should be called in App delegate...?

Comment: I received push notification in all state i.e. when app is in forground, background, close(terminated)..!
but my problem is that how to increment badge count when app is in background state and close (terminate) state???? 
Please tell me in details how i do it....?
my app badge count is only increase when app is in forground state.....?

if possible please tell me in brief.......!for Swift 3

Comment: Yes, you can update the badge without registering for remote notifications, just do: `application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = <number you want>`

Answer (score 0):

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = NotifCount
```