# Swift - Put Red Dot on iPhone App Icon

Tags: iphone, swift, icons

Any ideas how to apply a red dot to the iPhone App icon - like the Mail or Messages' Icon with the number of unread messages in it?

[image]

Comment: Local notifications, using badges

Comment: A dozen of tutorials online..

Comment: Or this one for Swift: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011118/add-badge-to-app-icon-in-ios-8-with-swift.

Comment: Many thanks - I was search under Red Dot rather than Badge or Notification. Thanks.

Comment: Used this code: // Set Noticification Level on App Icon Badge Number
            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: UIUserNotificationType.Badge,
                                                      categories: nil)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 123

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

### Swift 2:

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1// or you value
```

Hope this helps!